# Unable to send file content along with http header in python

Tags: python, html

I have a file and I'm reading it as follows.
[Ignoring all the connection related parameters]

```
somefile=open(/path/to/some/file,'rb')
READ_somefile=somefile.read()
somefile.close()
client_connection.send((str.encode('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: image/png\n\n')))
client_connection.send((READ_somefile))
```

I'm able to properly display my html webpage when I used the above code.
But I want to use only one send instead of two and there comes the issue.
I tried using the following

```
client_connection.send((str.encode('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: image/png\n\n',READ_somefile)))
```

I get the below error.

```
client_connection.send((str.encode('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: image/png\n\n',READ_somefile)))
TypeError: encode() argument 1 must be str, not bytes
```

Then I tried using this.

```
client_connection.send((str.encode('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: image/png\n\n',str(READ_somefile))))
```

I get the following error.

```
client_connection.send((str.encode('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: image/png\n\n',str(READ_somefile))))
LookupError: unknown encoding: b'/*!
```

Can you please let me know what kind of encoding should I use here to send both headers and content in same hit?

Please note that I can't use any external modules.

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying to send a webpage using pure python? You're not using a web framework like flask? Happy to help, just looking for some more info. Cheers!

Comment: Hi Yeah, I'm using python to create a simple web server and then send a webpage. No external modules or frameworks used.

Comment: Everything is working fine except that I'm unable to figure out the proper encoding and decoding here.

Comment: What sort of object is client_connection? It may only be possible to send using two statements depending on the behaviour

Comment: Looks like send() accepts bytes. Try `connection.send(bytes(header) + png_data))`

Comment: I don't think so because a standard http response can be sent using a single send to the socket.

Comment: Hi Amarghosh, getting the error "TypeError: string argument without an encoding"

Answer (score 0):

The signature is `socket.send(bytes[, flags])` - so

1. you want to pass a byte string
2. you want to pass it as a single argument

What you have are

1. a header `'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: image/png\n\n'` which currently is a unicode string so need to be encoded as a byte string
2. a body (the image's binary data) which is already a byte string so don't need to be encoded

The obvious solutions would be:

```
with open(/path/to/some/file,'rb') as somefile:
    body = somefile.read()
header = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: image/png\n\n'.encode()
payload = header + body
client_connection.send(payload)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot . So is it safe to assume that given any file, be it text or image first needs to be converted to binary and then send it?